# Requiring modules in React-Native without transforming them

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, commonjs, babeljs

I wanted to know if there's a way to load some modules in React-Native apps without transforming them. In my case, I'm trying to load a module which is already bundled, meaning that there's no need to transform it a second time. I know that React-Native supports blacklisting by defining a custom config, but still, this is not what I'm looking for, because it will ignore the required files completely. I've also tried to set an ignore rule in my `.babelrc` file, but I received the following error message after compiling:

> cannot read property 'token' of undefined

Here's an example of the effect I'm trying to achieve:

```
import {foo} from './my-raw-module';
import {bar} from './my-transformed-module;
```

I would like to somehow tell the packager that `my-raw-module` should be loaded as is, without going through the `babel` compiler. Do you have any ideas? Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!